# How do I stop my flatbread from going hard like pizza crust?

Tags: baking, bread, pizza, italian-cuisine, flatbread

Whenever I make flatbread, I can never get it soft and chewy on the inside AND outside, like storebought flatbread.

It always ends up like pizza crust, crunchy on the outside and somewhat softer inside; in addition, when left overnight, it just goes rock-hard, crunchy throughout.

Any thoughts on how to get softer flatbread?

Comment: What's your recipe and technique?

Comment: How are you cooking them? In an oven, on some manner of hotplate, in an oven on a pizza stone? I *think* that generally speaking oven cooked flatbreads tend to be more crusty than those cooked on a hot surface.

Comment: The most important info is left out here. Please [edit] the info requested by the other commenrs into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Store-bought has had time to allow crust to soften.
The inside/surface moisture balances out especially when wrapped.

Mostly it's the other way around trying to hold onto crisp outside and still soft inside!

Don't overtake and after a short cooling down, wrap and wait.

Otherwise, adjust baking to hold more moisture by partially covering or introducing steam.